# Make array of specific items within a pager and select specific class

Tags: jquery, arrays, pager

My question is: how do I make array of specific items within a pager and select specific class
This is my next/previous **(pager)** html code:

```
<div class="item-list">
<ul class="pager" style="display: none;">
<li class="pager-current">1</li>
<li class="pager-item">
<a class="active" title="Go to page 1" href="/challenges?page=1">2</a>
</li>
<li class="pager-next">
<a class="active" title="Go to next page" href="/challenges?page=2">next ›</a>
</li>
<li class="pager-last">
<a class="active" title="Go to last page" href="/challenges?page=3">last »</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

A pager looks like this: <--- previous 1 **2** 3 next ---> where you can go to next page.

I want to loop thru all pages 1 - 100.

Select each page, get the content and make a array of all elements with `<div class="items">` but only only the ones that has a class included named `<div id="allowed"></div>`

The page content:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="link"></div>
    <div class="allowed"></div>
  </div>
</div>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="title"></div>
    <div class="body"></div>
    <div class="link"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Now is the element with the allowed class only be inserted into the array, and the other one ignored.

Comment: I don't believe that this should be handled with JavaScript, instead you should use a server-side scripting language (such as [tag:php], [tag:ruby], [tag:.net]...).

Comment: all scripts within the sites are jquery, so javascript is the only option for me.

Comment: Let me see if I understand: you want [tag:javascript] to retrieve each page of your site, open it, look for a div with a class of 'allowed', and then open it? Or add that page's url to an array?

Comment: not open it, add it to the array so I can use it later for a filter.

Comment: What's the question? And your "rationale" for only being able to use Javascript makes no sense.

Comment: It's "jQuery", not "Jquery", and please stop tagging titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you make an array with the items that have a child which contains an element which has the class allowed.  Is this what you were looking for?

```
var $items = $("div.items");
var yourArray;

$.each($items,function(){
   if($(this).children(".allowed").length){
       yourArray.push($(this));
   }  
});
```

Comment: Indeed; but it reads like he wants to examine other pages on his site to see if those pages have an `.allowed` element, and if they do add their URL to an array. But I could be wrong in my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`jQuery.fn.has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to filter down a jQuery object based on the contents of it:

```
$('.items') // <-- all items
  .has('div.allowed') // <-- only the items with a <div class="allowed" />
```

or put it in the initial selector like this:

```
$('.items:has(div.allowed)');
```